# Perl script is running slow when calling bash

Tags: bash, perl

I am running a perl script that calls another script.  Via command line. But it runs extremely slow. The back ticks makes it run via command line.

```
for my $results (@$data){
  `/home/data/push_to_web $results->{file}`;
}
```

If i run the same command via bash `/home/data/push_to_web book.txt` the same script runs extremely fast.  If i build a bash file that contains

```
/home/data/push_to_web book_one.txt
/home/data/push_to_web book_two.txt
/home/data/push_to_web book_three.txt
```

The code executes extremely fast. Is there any secret to speeding perl up via another perl script.

Comment: I'd start by using `system '/home/data/push_to_web', $results->{file};`. No sense in using backticks if you're not capturing its output, more reliable with arguments with spaces in them, and doesn't require starting a shell first.

Comment: After those changes, you're doing pretty much exactly what the shell does.

Comment: @newdeveloper : Aside from the fact that the use of backticks does not make sense in your case - if you don't want to see the output of `push_to_wb`, just redirect stdout to `/dev/null`, you are spawning at least one child process (maybe more, depending on how `push_to_web` is written) for each element of `@$data`. You could optimize `push_to_web` with this in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Your perl script fires up a new bash shell for each element in the array, whereas running the commands in bash from a file doesn't have to create any new shells.

Depending on how many files you have, and what's in your bash startup files, this could add a significant overhead.

One option would be to build a list of semicolon-separated commands in the for loop, and then run one system command at the end to execute them all in one bash process.